# Does each and every subdirectory require its own ssl certificate?

Tags: ssl-certificate

We plan to have an X.509 certificate for our web server which is running multiple independent web applications. Those web applications are running on the same web server but are not related to each other (accessed by `www.maindomain.com/sub1`, `/sub2` and so on). If we have a certificate issued for the main domain, in order to secure each web application using TLS, do we still need a certificate for each and every web application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The sub folders (not sub-domains as mentioned) are all protected by the cert at the main level.

It gets interesting if your applications were deployed as actual subdomains like "sub1.maindomain.com", "sub2.maindomain.com", etc. You'd either need a wildcard cert or subject alternate names (SANs) on them.

Comment: Currently we use the IP address to access the web server. It is OK to issue ssl cert for an IP addresss as online posts say. It is great if one ssl cert for the IP is going to cover each and every web applications running on the same server box.

Comment: I meant a public IP address.

Comment: The SSL certificate is bound to a common name, which may be a traditional domain name, wildcard cert, or specific IP. If your server uses different IPs for each of the sub-directories, then you'd need a different cert for each IP used. If all share the same public IP, then you shouldn't have a problem.